# Is there a way to make an item that has extra armor or armor toughness?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I wanted to make a pair of Elytra wings that you could get on my private server after going to a specific point that unlike all other elytra would actually give you armor points(which show up above your hearts) just like any armor piece. I have seen this done with other armor just not the commands themselves used to make these items. I also HAD done some research to ensure that there was a way to do it before I came here and I couldn't find one.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Why not use protection?

Comment: @Frank I did in fact try to solve it myself but being the command newbie that I am I couldn't figure it out which is when I went to my search engine and try to search it up.

Comment: @ModDL because I want it to have the same effect as a diamond chestplate and the protection and since I can't seem to use math to find the perfect number of protection levels for the same number of armor points as a diamond chestplate I decided to do this instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using attribute modifiers, they can be used to modify anything from health to attack speed to hunger to armor value. The command your looking for is like this:

```
/give @p elytra 1 0 {AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.armor",Name:"Test",Amount:6,Operation:0,UUIDLeast:1l,UUIDMost:1l,Slot:"chest"}]}
```

Where it says `Amount:6` that is how many half armor points it is so eight is the equivalent of a diamond chestplate.